# Where does gcc come from when using linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm a Linux beginner, and I don't know the commands details now.

I have a question about where I can get some packages. For example, when I want to get "gcc", I entered "yum install gcc". Where does it come from -- on the Internet? Or does Linux have it from the beginning?

I was a Windows user, and then I went to websites to get "gcc" and download it at the page. I'm puzzled where I can get "gcc" from.

Comment: google says https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9934

Comment: It depends. Which Linux system are you running? (Ubuntu? Fedora?) Many Linux distributions come with gcc preinstalled. Did you try typing `gcc`? What exactly happened when you typed `yum install gcc`?

Comment: This is no programming question within the rules of this site. It is about system administration. How about reading the documentation of your distribution?

Comment: >Keith Thompson I'm using fedora, and when type yum install gcc, it seemed to sucess, and I can use gcc. >Olaf I'm sorry, I didn't understand well.

Comment: You need to use "@", not ">", to tag someone in a comment. Click the "help" link next to the comment entry box. I only saw your response by chance. So you're using Fedora, you used `yum install gcc`, it worked, and you can use `gcc`. It doesn't sound like you have a problem. Are you just asking how `yum install` works? Have you tried `man yum`?

Answer (score -1):

Entering the command "yum install gcc" directly install thepackage in your files.
It's like in Windows when you donwload something it goes in your Download file, except packages go usually on /usr/bin.

Doing "sudo apt-get install gcc" is also a possibility.